# как вывести содержимое объекта в этом компоненте?

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

мне приходит такой ответ с сервера
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так я делаю запрос на получение данных в компоненте:

```js
computed: {
  ...mapGetters([
    'showNews'
  ]),

  },
  mounted() {
     this.$store.dispatch('newsById', this.id /* в компонент передается props id */);
  }
```

так выглядит `newsById` в `action` в store/index.js:

```js
newsById({ commit }, id) {
  axios.get(`/news/${id}`, apiConfig)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
        commit('newsByIdMutation', response);
    })
}
```

так выглядит `newsByIdMutation` в `mutations` в store/index.js:

```js
newsByIdMutation(state, newsById) {
  state.showNews = newsById.data;
}
```

в разметке компонента я пытаюсь получить доступ к этому объекту таким образом `{{ showNews.title }}`, `{{ showNews.text }}` и прочее. но получаю ошибку: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'title_img' of undefined` . как мне получить эти свойства в объекте который я получаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Vue` полагается на данные. Рендеринг всегда синхронный. Компонент не ждет завершения каких-либо вызовов `axios`, прежде чем он попытается отобразить шаблон.

Вот типичная ситуация - как возникает ошибка подобная той, что в вопросе:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    obj: undefined
  },
  mounted(){
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.obj = {
        title: 'Title'
      }
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{ obj.title }}
</div>
```

Несмотря на то, что в данном примере `title` успешно вмонтировано в шаблон (благодаря реактивности), на стадии рендеринга мы получили ошибку, которая уведомила нас о том, что шаблон использует данные, которые не определены ( потому что на стадии рендеринга `vue` получает `obj` как `undefined` и не найдя объявленного в шаблоне свойства `title` - выводит ошибку).

Чтобы не допустить возникновения такого рода ошибок, вы должны использовать директиву `v-if` ([условная отрисовка](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)) (в шаблоне компонента или в самом компоненте, в родительском шаблоне) для обработки ситуации, когда компонент уже отображается, но данных еще нет.

Перепишем пример, чтобы исключить возникновение ошибки:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    obj: undefined
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.obj = {
        title: 'Title'
      }
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template v-if="obj">
    {{ obj.title }}
  </template>
</div>
```